# Listen click event from anchor tag with renderer in Angular

Tags: angular

I have different anchor tags on my news article when click on specific anchor tag based on that i have to navigate to that page.

its working fine with addEventListener like this

```
 var anchors = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName("a"); 

    if (anchors.length != 0) {
      for (var i = 0, length = anchors.length; i < length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];
        anchor.addEventListener('click', this.handlelinks.bind(this))
      };
    }
```

now i have to listen with every anchor tag click with angular renderer like

```
var anchors = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName("a"); 

    if (anchors.length != 0) {
      for (var i = 0, length = anchors.length; i < length; i++) {
        var anchor = anchors[i];
        this.renderer.listen(this.element.nativeElement, 'click', this.handlelinks.bind(this))
      };
    }
```

but its listen every click in page how can i achieve this with anchor tag click only.

Answer (score 0):

With Angular, you can simply add en event listener from your template with the "()" notation.
For exemple, if you can to listen to the click event on links :

```
<a (click)="handleLink()">My link</a>
```

And in your class :

```
class MyComponent {

   handleLink () { // do your stuff }

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: No you misunderstood. I am not getting tags from template. I have text that comes from database contains anchor tags i have to listen and get class name when click on anchor tag from news article.

Comment: You're getting your links from a database ? You say you can click on them, then how do you display them first ?

Comment: Actually i have converted href with class in my backend then when user click on anchor tag i get class name then navigate based on class name value.